# bundle install errors with gems, statistics2-0.54 (ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems, bundle

I am dealing with a bundle install error, described below

on Ubuntu `20.04.2 LTS`

I am using `ruby-2.5.5`, installed with **rvm** manager

`gem install bundle` --> executes successfully

`bundle install` --> prints error

```
Installing statistics2 0.54 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

...

An error occurred while installing statistics2 (0.54), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install statistics2 -v '0.54' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  abanalyzer was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
    statistics2
```

when running command `gem install statistics2 -v '0.54'`
prints error

```
ERROR:  Error installing statistics2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/*USER*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/statistics2-0.54/ext
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby -I /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20210601-71318-1da18jl.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile 

...

make install failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/*USER*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/statistics2-0.54 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/*USER*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/statistics2-0.54/gem_make.out
```

I have successfully installed depndences:
`sudo apt install gcc libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev -y`
and
`sudo apt install libssl-dev`
and
`sudo apt install ruby-dev`

then run `bundle update`
then run `gem update --system`

then run `bundle install` which gives again the above error.

`bundle env`

gives

````
Bundler             2.1.4
  Platforms         ruby, x86_64-linux
Ruby                2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-linux]
  Full Path         /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby
  Config Dir        /etc
RubyGems            3.2.19
  Gem Home          /home/*USER*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5
  Gem Path          /home/*USER*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  User Home         /home/*USER*
  User Path         /home/*USER*/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  Bin Dir           /home/*USER*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/bin
Tools               
  Git               2.25.1
  RVM               1.29.12 latest
  rbenv             not installed
  chruby            not installed
  rubygems-bundler  (1.4.5)

...

### Gemfile

```ruby
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# rails
gem 'rails', '5.2.0'
gem 'rails-dom-testing'
gem 'redis-rails'
````

Could you please have a look at this error and hopefully someone has an answer.
Is it smth wrong with my bundle version for ruby-2.5.5, or smth else wrong with gems installations or smth else?

Kind Regards,

Comment: `sudo apt install gcc` will not install a fully functional gcc. Hence `build-essential` which installs libc6-dev etc. ... `rake` is missing too in your "dependency" list, I think.

Comment: libc6-dev is already install. How do I install rake?

Comment: Install `rake` : Just like any other Ubuntu package https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/rake

Comment: apparently rake is already installed and the last version :|

Comment: Still unresolved. anyone has some clearer guide?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question

> Is it smth wrong with my bundle version for ruby-2.5.5, or smth else wrong with gems installations or smth else?

There are some dependencies missing on your system, it's not linked to your bundle or ruby version or other gems

`statistics2` is a gem using native extension so it expects some advanced system requirements to build (like make & gcc to compile the file `_statistics2.c`)

I managed to install it myself on a Ubuntu(20.04.2 LTS like you)

```sh
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using bundler 1.17.3
Fetching statistics2 0.54
Installing statistics2 0.54 with native extensions
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
```

I don't know exactly the required libraries as the gem is quite old ([2010](https://github.com/abscondment/statistics2/releases/tag/0.54)) and not documented.

Could you try a more recent gem ([distribution](https://github.com/clbustos/distribution)) that seems to offer the same features ?

> Distribution is a gem with several probabilistic distributions. Pure Ruby is used by default, C (GSL) or Java extensions are used if available.

```rb
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'distribution'
```

It's also pure ruby so you shouldn't have problem with native extensions while `bundle install` :

```sh
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using bundler 1.17.3
Using distribution 0.8.0
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Alexis
Don't really know how to install a different gem distribution. doesn't seem that straight forward